# Change the text at the top right of the chart object

Tags: c#

I guess it's a simple thing, but i tried to do it myself and couldn't find it. When I add data to the chart object, I print the names of the data on the right side label. My question is, "How can I change the background color or other properties of this label or can i?" And that's my code that adds columns:

```
chart1.Series.Clear();
chart1.Series.Add($"{donusumMiktari} {neyden} / {neye}");
double bidPriceVal = Convert.ToDouble(bidPrice) * donusumMiktari;
chart1.Series[$"{donusumMiktari} {neyden} / {neye}"]. Points.AddXY("Teklif Fiyat", bidPriceVal);
double askPriceVal = Convert.ToDouble(askPrice) * donusumMiktari;
chart1.Series[$"{donusumMiktari} {neyden} / {neye}"]. Points.AddXY("Alış Fiyatı", askPriceVal);"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the background color of the legend you can add the following code after you've added the series to the chart

```
// Get the legend object of the chart
var legend = chart1.Legends[0];

// Set the background color of the legend
legend.BackColor = Color.LightGray
```